# Which thread for non-GUI graphics?

Tags: java, graphics

For the first time, I'm writing a Java application that is graphics-intensive without a GUI. It generates images by creating a BufferedImage and working with its Graphics2D object. Images are written to files using ImageIO.write.

I need to decide whether to work in the main thread, or the Event Dispatch Thread.

In favor of the EDT, I would do all the graphics updates in the EDT if I were writing a GUI.

In favor of the main thread, the application will compute continuously for the whole time it is running, without any user interaction to break things up.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your arguments "in favor of ...". Maybe you could expand/clarify.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If I had really clear, solid arguments either way I would know the answer. I'm afraid my thinking on this is a bit fuzzy.

Comment: So why would you consider using anything than your main thread, having in mind all the ugly anon classes you'll need to transfer control to/from the EDT?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Just the usual advice to do graphics work in the EDT.

Comment: That is a misunderstanding. All GUI work belongs in the EDT, not non-GUI graphics processing. And: Without GUI you don't have an EDT (at least automatically)...

Comment: AFAIK that is more a restriction than advice. Since at least some work is done on the EDT (through the events), and since GUI code is not thread-safe, that forces you to do everything on the EDT. Since your code won't involve any "heavyweight" GUI components, and no events, then the restriction doesn't apply (at least I can't see a reason).

Comment: *"Which thread for non-GUI graphics?"*  Non EDT is what I would have guessed (and the way I've always coded it).  But could you confirm, does the app. *have* a GUI?

Comment: `without a GUI.` - then there is no EDT. `Just the usual advice to do graphics work in the EDT` - painting using the Graphics object of a GUI component is done on the EDT. But you are using the Graphics object of a BufferedImage which has nothing to do with a GUI component so you would just use a regular Thread.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, the app does not have a GUI. It needs to be able to run unattended.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. There seems to be a clear consensus that the EDT issue only applies if there will be GUI activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which thread for non-GUI graphics?

Non EDT is what I would have guessed (and the way I've always coded it).

But could you confirm, does the app. have a GUI?

> No, the app does not have a GUI. It needs to be able to run unattended.

That settles it, forget the EDT & use whatever `Thread` you like (including the default one given to the app.).